# Grouping similar elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there any better efficient algorithm or pre-built function which can group similar elements inside list and return a list of their indexes.

By similar, I mean rounding off the numbers inside list resulting same are similar

Also, the list isn't sorted, My aim is to have indices according to unsorted list

For example,

```
data = [11.12438802,  #0  -+
       11.31071615,   #1   |
       11.2988151,    #2   |
       11.29753906,   #3  -+
       17.46925781,   #4  -+
       17.77536458,   #5   |
       17.7358724,    #6  -+
       16.64058594,   #7  -+
       16.64875,      #8  -+
       8.091575521,   #9  -+
       8.089322917,   #10  |
       8.084231771,   #11  |
       8.08842447,    #12  |
       8.072473958,   #13  |
       8.034036458]   #14 -+
```

My expected result is `indexes = [ [0,3] , [4,6] , [7,8] , [9,14] ]`

Comment: Also, is your list always sorted like your sample data?

Comment: @timgeb Ohh, okay let me edit, Nope it is not sorted, I just edited my question

Comment: Your list is still sorted in the sense that similar elements are consecutive. Is this always the case?

Comment: @timgeb No , its not always sorted, There is a pattern of 11,17,16,8, and so on random

Comment: but similar elements are always consecutive?

Comment: Check out [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)? Otherwise, can you explain why you expect that result? To get the best answers on stack overflow, check out this post on creating [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @timgeb By similar, I mean rounding off the numbers inside list resulting same are similar, like [11.12,11.13,11.21] etc are similar as we round off them.  These three numbers are similar in that sense, Sorry, I am not native English speaker, I might have used wrong vocab

Comment: I want to know if this can happen: `[11.12, 11.13, 11.21, 25.1, 25.2, 11.32]`.

Comment: @timgeb `[11.12, 11.13, 11.21, 25.1, 25.2, 11.32]` According to me, this should be like `[[11.12,11.13,11.21],[25.1,25.2],[11.32]]]` which should give me `indexes = [[0,2],[3,4],[5]]`

Comment: alright, understood!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groups = groupby(enumerate(data), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
>>> lists = (list(g[1]) for g in groups)
>>> [[l[0][0], l[-1][0]] for l in lists]
[[0, 3], [4, 6], [7, 8], [9, 14]]
```

Answer (score 3):

TL/DR: Some explaining - answer about halfway down.

You seem to be sorting based on the full number. You can use a `defaultdict(list)` to add all numbers for your list into it, use as key the `int(num)` (or the rounded value you want to group by) of the number you are adding - storing the num and its index lets you get the indexes.

Caveat: This will group numbers wherever they are inside the list - it does not respect "subgroups" and should be used with sorted data to avoid things like `[3.4, 3.6, 7.1, 3.1]` => `[[0,3],[2,2]]`.

### From the dict you can create your grouped list:

```
data = [11.12438802,  #0  -+
       11.31071615,   #1   |
       11.2988151,    #2   |
       11.29753906,   #3  -+
       17.46925781,   #4  -+
       17.77536458,   #5   |
       17.7358724,    #6  -+
       16.64058594,   #7  -+
       16.64875,      #8  -+
       8.091575521,   #9  -+
       8.089322917,   #10  |
       8.084231771,   #11  |
       8.08842447,    #12  |
       8.072473958,   #13  |
       8.034036458]  

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for num in data:
    d[int(num)].append(num) 

print(d)

k = []
for _, num in d.items():
    k.extend(num)

print(k)
```

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    16: [16.64058594, 16.64875], 
    17: [17.46925781, 17.77536458, 17.7358724], 
    11: [11.12438802, 11.31071615, 11.2988151, 11.29753906], 
     8: [8.091575521, 8.089322917, 8.084231771, 8.08842447, 8.072473958, 8.034036458]})

[16.64058594, 16.64875, 17.46925781, 17.77536458, 17.7358724, 11.12438802,
 11.31071615, 11.2988151, 11.29753906, 8.091575521, 8.089322917, 8.084231771,
  8.08842447, 8.072473958, 8.034036458]
```

### How to get the index ranges from that:

If you alter this slightly and store the indexes instead (and use themin/max), you are done:

```
data = [11.12438802,  #0  -+
       11.31071615,   #1   |
       11.2988151,    #2   |
       11.29753906,   #3  -+
       17.46925781,   #4  -+
       17.77536458,   #5   |
       17.7358724,    #6  -+
       16.64058594,   #7  -+
       16.64875,      #8  -+
       8.091575521,   #9  -+
       8.089322917,   #10  |
       8.084231771,   #11  |
       8.08842447,    #12  |
       8.072473958,   #13  |
       8.034036458]  

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx,num in enumerate(data):
    d[int(num)].append(idx)            # Add the index instead of the number


indexes = []
for _, v in d.items():
    indexes.append([min(v),max(v)])    # get the min/max, use [n[0],v[-1]] if presorted
indexes.sort()                         # sort em
print(indexes)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [4, 6], [7, 8], [9, 14]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving such a good explanation! Can't I mark both answers ?

Comment: @rish only one can be "the" answer :) - it's fine, the only thing it gives are imaginary internet points - the groupby version might be better suited  if you have subgroups so its more versatile. your data was sorted so this works for that data as well.